# Compare 2 or more sorted arrays javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to handroll a solution for poker. I've gotten all the logic to determine the best 5 card hand. I'm having issues comparing multiple arrays for which have higher elements in the event of ties(with regard to hand type).

Say we have some potential winners for a flush.

```
var low_flush = [2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
var medium_flush = [3, 4, 5, 6, 8]
var high_flush = [2, 3, 4, 5, 9]
```

I want to build a function that i pass any number of arrays to and it returns the "highest poker hand" or an array of hands in the event of an actual tie:

```
function bestHand(hands){
  // 
  return high_hand
}
```

Everything I've read thus far is how to compare just two arrays, and usually with that, it only sees if there are equal to each other. If it helps heres my [source code](https://github.com/andrewsunglaekim/let_it_burn_async_poker)

My first thoughts are to iterate over the hands. And for each iteration, iterate over the hands again for comparison. Just thinking about this pseudocode is making my head hurt and was thinking their might be a more elegant solution for this and/or library(not a poker library though)

I am using underscore in other parts of the codebase so feel free to use it in answer as well!

Comment: The pseudocode is pretty much just the rules of poker.  For flushes, compare the highest cards.  If still tied, compare the next highest.  Keep comparing until either you find a winner or you reach the 5 card limit.

Comment: yeah, i was thinking there way a better way then nested loops and lotsa breaks/nexts

Comment: FWIW, iterating is the correct solution here.  That's based on the rules of poker themselves.  You can use stuff like underscore to wrap up some of the iterative logic into a more presentable form, but ultimately you are going to have to iterate over both hands.

Comment: I think i have a better way that doesn't use iteration. I think i can reverse the order, concatenate the elements as a string, parse that result in to an integer and then just compare the values

Comment: Be careful with that approach.  While that will work for basic stuff like flushes and straights, that will fail for comparing stuff like 2 pair.  And string concatenation is still internally iterating the array.

Comment: Great point, but the way my decider model is going about it is it returns kickers for pairs and 2 pair. So i can just pass the kickers in. Thanks for helping me through this! @ryanyuyu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may seem silly. But this seems to work for me.

```
var hands = [ [2, 3, 4, 5, 7], [2, 3, 5, 9, 8], [2, 3, 4, 5, 9] ];
var values = [];
function bestHand(hands){ 
   hands.forEach(function(arr, index) {
    var temp = arr.slice();
    values[index] = parseInt(temp.sort().reverse().join(''));
   });
   var max = Math.max.apply(Math, values);
   return hands[values.indexOf(max)];
}
bestHand(hands);
```

Comment: I was too late with mine! yeah, i think i'm gonna go with this sort of thing, thanks @SarathChandra

Comment: Well, I'm glad I could help. :)

Comment: so you consider that [1,3,5,6,7] is better than [1,1,1,1,2] ? I'm not an expert in poker but its definitely not the right answer

Comment: Well. That's the catch. This function does not expect 1s. If you intend to check for an ace or any figure card, the values should be as follows: J-11, Q-12, K-13, A-14. And hence, as pointed by @Redu, taking the sum (simple or suit weighted) should be fine.

Comment: check this variant: [[5,7,8,9,K], [2,3,5,10,J]]. Hands with multiple card values greater or equal than 10 can return wrong results: 14 9 < 11 10

Comment: @TimB it wont ever draw that comparison, i have a model that decides what the hands are. The only time a tie breaker happens is when both hands are flushes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) first to count the sum of each array

```
var total3 = high_flush.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
  return previousValue + currentValue;
}, 0);
```

after that push each one to an array with `total` of array and the name of the `winner`

```
allhands.push({total: total1 , name: "low_flush"});
```

then compare them with compare function and sort you array

```
function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.total < b.total)
    return -1;
  else if (a.total > b.total)
    return 1;
  else 
    return 0;
}
allhands.sort(compare);
```

**Working** example here:

```js
var low_flush = [2, 3, 4, 5, 7];
var medium_flush = [2, 3, 4, 5, 8];
var high_flush = [2, 3, 4, 5, 9];
var allhands = [];

var total3 = high_flush.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
  return previousValue + currentValue;
}, 0);
allhands.push({total: total3 , name: "high_flush"});

var total1 = low_flush.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
  return previousValue + currentValue;
}, 0);
allhands.push({total: total1 , name: "low_flush"});

var total2 = medium_flush.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
  return previousValue + currentValue;
}, 0);
allhands.push({total: total2 , name: "medium_flush"});


function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.total < b.total)
    return -1;
  else if (a.total > b.total)
    return 1;
  else 
    return 0;
}
allhands.sort(compare);

console.log("The winner is "+allhands[allhands.length - 1].name +"With total:"+ allhands[allhands.length - 1].total );
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can't do sum of an array. Compare `[2, 3, 4, 5, 10]` and `[4, 6, 7, 8, 9]` The reduce will make the second array higher, but in actuality the 10 high is the best hand.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you need to pass an array of hand objects to something like this.

```
function getBest(...hands){
    return hands.sort((p,c) => p.weight() <= c.weight() ? -1:1)[hands.length-1]
}
```

when it comes to finding out the weight of a hand object in tie conditions it could be first determined by the hands color (spades beats all) and then by sum of the card values for clubs like 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11(j),12(q),13(k),14(a). The sum of them all is 104 so for diamonds card values can be (104+2), (104+3), (104+4) etc.. for hearts you offset values by 208 and for spades by 312.

```
hand.prototype.weight = function(){
                          return this.reduce((p,c) => p.value + c.value)
                        }
```

Of course this will only handle the tie conditions. It can not tell a flush from a flush royale.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at array's reduce function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Example:

```js
var result = hands.reduce(function(prevHand, currentHand) {
    return compareHands(prevHand,currentHand) ? prevHand : currentHand;
});
```

This answers the question about comparing multiples arrays, but keep in mind that it will reduce it to one value, this may not be the perfect solution since you have to consider draws. In that case your result should be an array, and in the comparison push into the array or reinitialize and add it to the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
function bestHands(DescOrderedHands){
  bestHand = DescOrderedHands[0]
  bestHandScore = parseInt(_.map(bestHand, function(num){return num.toString}).join(""))
  _.each(DescOrderedHands, function(hand){
    stringHand = _.map(hand, function(num){return num.toString}).join("")
    if (parseInt(stringHand) > bestHandScore){
      bestHand = hand
    } 

  }
  return bestHand
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, You have to be sure that all arrays in your your function have the same length, then you have to sort each array, and finally you have to compare each value of each array.

You should have something like this

```
function bestHand(hands){
  var best_hand = null;
  for(var i = 0; i < hands.length; ++i){
    hands[i] = hands[i].sort();
    if(i > 0){
      for(var j = 0; j < hands[i].length; ++j){
        if(best_hand[j] < hands[i][j]){
          best_hand = hands[i];
          break;
        }
        else if(best_hand[j] > hands[i][j]){
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      best_hand = hands[i];
    }
  }

  return best_hand;
}
```

Be sure you pass arrays with the same length in argument